# Fix My Custom Function: Remove Automatic <p>

Tags: php, functions

I want to remove the automatic paragraph tag that goes around my excerpts, which are being outputted by a custom function.  I'd really appreciate if you could tell me what to add to my code.

I'm using this custom function for excerpts:

```
  // Default length (by WordPress)
  public static $length = 25;

  // So you can call: my_excerpt('short');
  public static $types = array(
      'short' => 5,
      'regular' => 25,
      'long' => 100
    );

  public static function length($new_length = 55) {
    Excerpt::$length = $new_length;
    add_filter('excerpt_length', 'Excerpt::new_length');
    Excerpt::output();
  }
  public static function new_length() {
    if( isset(Excerpt::$types[Excerpt::$length]) )
      return Excerpt::$types[Excerpt::$length];
    else
      return Excerpt::$length;
  }
  public static function output() {
    the_excerpt();
  }
}

// An alias to the class
function my_excerpt($length = 25) {
  Excerpt::length($length);
}
```

and calling it using

```
<?php my_excerpt('short'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I think adding `remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );` around when you have `add_filter('excerpt_length', 'Excerpt::new_length');` does what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I know two good techniques that work fine with shortcodes and should work with excerpts as well.

You're able to parse excerpt's content using:

```
function my_excerpt( $content ) {

    /* Parse nested shortcodes and add formatting. */
    $content = trim( wpautop( do_shortcode( $content ) ) );

    /* Remove '</p>' from the start of the string. */
    if ( substr( $content, 0, 4 ) == '</p>' )
        $content = substr( $content, 4 );

    /* Remove '<p>' from the end of the string. */
    if ( substr( $content, -3, 3 ) == '<p>' )
        $content = substr( $content, 0, -3 );

    /* Remove any instances of '<p></p>'. */
    $content = str_replace( array( '<p></p>' ), '', $content );

    return $content;
}
```

In addition there is technique using [raw] shortcode:

```
function my_formatter($content) {
    $new_content = '';
    $pattern_full = '{(\[raw\].*?\[/raw\])}is';
    $pattern_contents = '{\[raw\](.*?)\[/raw\]}is';
    $pieces = preg_split($pattern_full, $content, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

    foreach ($pieces as $piece) {
        if (preg_match($pattern_contents, $piece, $matches)) {
            $new_content .= $matches[1];
        } else {
            $new_content .= wptexturize(wpautop($piece));
        }
    }

    return $new_content;
}

remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');

add_filter('the_content', 'my_formatter', 99);
```

I hope it helps.

If you want us to help you with your function - it is always a good idea to say what is wrong with the function in the first place?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the function.  Wordpress automatically adds paragraph tags to excerpts, I want to remove the paragraph tags for this excerpt.